# Cogroup 5 RDD (get Tuple5 or more)

Tags: java, apache-spark, tuples

I would like to know if it is possible in Spark to create a Tuple5 of RDDs.
I only manage to get Tuple4 but no more.

```
    JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple4<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>, Iterable<Fish>, Iterable<Monkey>>>

    JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Cat> RDD1 = getRDD1();
    JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Dog> RDD2 = getRDD2();
    JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Fish> RDD3 = getRDD3();
    JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Monkey> RDD4 = getRDD4();
    JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Cow> RDD5 = getRDD5();

    return RDD1.cogroup(RDD2, RDD3, RDD4);
```

How would you do something like this :

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple5<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>, Iterable<Fish>, Iterable<Monkey>, Iterable<Cow>>> = RDD1.cogroup(RDD2, RDD3, RDD4, RDD5);
```

I really need those cows :)

Thank you

Comment: I am also looking for answer of same, if you found any leads please share

Comment: @rohit We went for another solution without cogroup... (late answer but it might help someone else)

Comment: can you give some idea what you did, i think you do some remodeling to avoid tuple of 5, but it would be nice to know idea.

Comment: @rohit See solution below. It is not ideal but it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

We did not use cogroup.
We created a superObject containing every lists.

For each one of the 5 RDDs :

```
oneOfThe5RDD.join(superRDD).mapToPair(tuple -> {

    SuperObject superObject = tuple._2()._1();
    superObject .setListXXX(IteratorUtils.toList(tuple._2()._2().iterator()));
    return new Tuple2<>(tuple._1(), superObject);
});
```